# How can I run javascript in rails webpage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a webpage with rails and I'm trying to run baguetteBox.js to create an image gallery. I've tried using <%= javascript_pack_tag 'gallery' %> at the top of the gallery page along with baguetteBox CSS and js script but it still not works. Hope that you can help me, thank you.

Comment: I think you should import it since it's a package,. so in your application.js do import baguetteBox from 'baguettebox.js';

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  Are you using webpacker or sprockets for your javascript?

Comment: Rails 6 and webpacker.

Comment: I’ve tried to import it as package but nothing happens Joel_Blum.

Answer (score 0):

if in your javascript you are looking from an element to mount on or change on click it has to be imported after the html with the same tag just at the end of the body

Comment: Do you mean javascript_pack_tag + js file name at the end? Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

To install baguetteBox need to run:

```
$ yarn add baguettebox.js
```

then you can create a file `app/javascript/js/gallery.js` with the following:

```
import baguetteBox from 'baguettebox.js';

# If you are not using turbolinks replace 'turbolinks:load' with 'DOMContentLoaded'
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    baguetteBox.run('.gallery');
})
```

then you can import that into your `application.js` file like so:

```
...
import '../js/gallery'
```

That should get you started.

Comment: I get this error in the browser - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './app/javascript/packs/gallery.js'
    at webpackMissingModule (application.js:1)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83